# Perform a function for x seconds on python

Tags: python, user-interface

I´m new in python programming. I´m trying to develop a software runing on `Raspy3`. The problem is, that I want a button to perform a function during x seconds (10 in this case). I tried using QTimer.singleshot, using Lambda, but it freezes my computer and windows console says something like:
`QEventDispatcherWin32::registertime: Failed to create a timer - the process has used the maximun number of handlers allowed by the system`(translated from spanish) 
Here is the code of the program:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import (QTime)
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import ui_1


class Ventana(QMainWindow, ui_1.Ui_Ventana):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ventana, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.botonBlanco.clicked.connect(self.blanco)       
        self.sliderBlanco.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderC)
        self.labelBlanco.setText("Toma muestra durante 60 segundos para setear el blanco")
        blancoA = False

    def blanco(self):
        cr = 0
        while cr != 10:
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: crono(cr))

    def crono(self, cr):
        cr += 1
        return cr

    def sliderC(self):
        tiempoBlanco = self.sliderBlanco.value()
        self.labelBlanco.setText("Toma muestra durante %i segundos para setear el blanco" % tiempoBlanco)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Ventana()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I am using Python 2.7.11 and PyQt 4 GUI
I don't know, how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure if this helps, but your lambda function isn't returning any variables when it's called, within `self.crono` the variable cr is private and any changes to it won't be made to the cr variable in the scope of `blanco`

Comment: @Aaron +1, also what do you mean by "perform a function during `x` seconds". I'm guessing you want to change the label for 1 second after a button is clicked?

Comment: @Aaron, that may explain the reason of the fail...I´ll check that.

Comment: @ÇağlarKutlu thats exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `blanco` cr never gets incremented. The value returned from crono function is not assigned anywhere. I never used PyQt(only Qt4 C++), but you can try this ( I don't know what your sliders are doing, so excuse me as I am gonna ignore them :) ):

Add your `__init__` this:

```
self.cr = 0
```

It seems your `blanco` function starts the timer, change it like this:

```
def blanco(self):
    if self.cr > 10:
        # don't start the sec counter if 10s passed
        self.cr = 0
    else:
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.crono)
```

You need to call blanco each second to reset the timer, also you need to do the action you want to do each second after crono gets called. So, do these two things in `crono`:

```
def crono(self):
    self.cr = self.cr + 1
    self.labelBlanco.setText("Total of %i seconds passed." % tiempoBlanco)
    self.blanco()
```

This should change the labelBlanco each second for a total of 10 seconds after the botonBlanco is pressed. Check if that works and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your `ui_1` module, I can't really debug this further, but this may solve an error you're having or will have once you solve your current problem..

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import (QTime)
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import ui_1


class Ventana(QMainWindow, ui_1.Ui_Ventana):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ventana, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.botonBlanco.clicked.connect(self.blanco)       
        self.sliderBlanco.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderC)
        self.labelBlanco.setText("Toma muestra durante 60 segundos para setear el blanco")
        blancoA = False

    def blanco(self):
        self.cr = 0
        while self.cr != 10:
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.crono)

    def crono(self):
        self.cr += 1

    def sliderC(self):
        tiempoBlanco = self.sliderBlanco.value()
        self.labelBlanco.setText("Toma muestra durante %i segundos para setear el blanco" % tiempoBlanco)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Ventana()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

note changes to `self.crono` in `Qtimer` call as well as changing instances of your `cr` variable to an object attribute: `self.cr`